# How to prevent user multiple click submit button error for a login form in react?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom, formik

I use formik and react-router-dom for my react login management. However, if click the submit button multiple times in a short time, after redirect to home page, there will be an error of
 "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in SignInForm (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:52)"
And the home page will be empty data after redirected.

I try to use setSubmitting(false) of formik to disable the button, how ever, if user enter wrong password, the button is also disabled. May I know what is wrong with my code and what would be a good method to handle this login situation? Thank you so much!

```js
 if (this.state.redirect) {
            return (<Redirect to={'/'} />)
        }

        if (sessionStorage.getItem('userToken')) {
            return (<Redirect to={'/'} />)
        }
```

```js
                    <Formik
                            initialValues={{
                                email: '',
                                password: ''

                            }}
                            validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                                email: Yup.string()
                                    .email()
                                    .required('Required'),
                                password: Yup.string()
                                    .required('Required'),
                            })}
                            onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                                axios.post('http://testtesttest/users/sign_in', {
                                    user: {
                                        email: values.email,
                                        password: values.password
                                    }
                                }).then(res => {

                                    setSubmitting(false);



                                    console.log(res.data);
                                    sessionStorage.setItem('userToken', res.data.auth_token);
                                    sessionStorage.setItem('userId', res.data.id);
                                    this.setState({ redirect: true });
                                }).catch(err => {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    alert('wrong email address or password');

                                })

                            }}
                            render={formProps => {

                                return (
                                    <Form className="FormFields">
                                        <div className="form-group ">
                                            <label htmlFor="email" className={this.state.emailActive ? "active" : ""}>Email</label>
                                            <Field
                                                type="text"
                                                name="email"


                                                className={formProps.errors.email && formProps.touched.email ? 'is-invalid form-control' : 'form-control'}

                                            />


                                            <ErrorMessage name="email"
                                                component="div"
                                                className="invalid-feedback" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                                            <Field
                                                type="text"
                                                name="password"


                                                className={formProps.errors.password && formProps.touched.password ? 'is-invalid form-control' : 'form-control'}
                                            />
                                            <ErrorMessage name="password"
                                                component="div"
                                                className="invalid-feedback" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="FormField">

                                            <button
                                                type="submit"
                                                disabled={formProps.isSubmitting }
                                                className="button emit-button emit-button-blue"
                                            >
                                                Submit
                                            </button>


                                        </div>

                                    </Form>


                                );
                            }}
                        />
```

```js
 <BrowserRouter >
        <div className="App">


          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home}>
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/management" component={Management}>
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/quotes/:quoteId(\d+)' component={Quote}></PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/quotes/new' component={NewQuote}></PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path='/cards/:cardId(\d+)' component={CardDetail}></PrivateRoute>


            <Route exact path="/sign-up" component={SignUpForm}>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/sign-in" component={SignInForm}>
            </Route>

            <Route component={Error}>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>

      </BrowserRouter >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution may be to move the setSubmitting(false); to before the post, (if it does not abort the post):

```
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {

    setSubmitting(false);

    axios.post('http://testtesttest/users/sign_in', {
```

Otherwise, a different solution could be to create a variable higher up to lock the function while it is busy. This will prevent further submissions until it has done its work.

```
var isSubmitLocked = false;
```

Then wrap your axios.post block in an if-statement and set the variable to true when busy and back to false when completed:

```
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {

  if(!isSubmitBlocked) {

    isSubmitBlocked = true;

    axios.post('http://testtesttest/users/sign_in', {
        user: {
            email: values.email,
            password: values.password
        }
    }).then(res => {

        console.log(res.data);
        sessionStorage.setItem('userToken', res.data.auth_token);
        sessionStorage.setItem('userId', res.data.id);
        this.setState({ redirect: true });

        isSubmitBlocked = false;

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert('wrong email address or password');

    isSubmitBlocked = false;
    })
  }

}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! It worked! I put the setSubmitting(true) once the user click the button and only set it to false if catch error then it worked! onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                                setSubmitting(true);
                                axios.post(..).then(res => {                                 
                                }).catch(err => {
                                    setSubmitting(false);
                                })

                            }}