# how to prevent form from submitting only if it catches error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to prevent the form from submitting only when i catch an error

i have this function linked to my form onSubmit

```
const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const submitForm = await axios.post(
                "http://localhost:5000/users/register",
                info
            );
            setError("");
        } catch (error) {
            const err = error.response.data.msg;
            setError(err);
            // display the msg on screen
        }
    };
```

right now i have **e.preventDefault()** on top which will stop the form and display response msg
but i only want that to happen if there was an error in the "catch"

otherwise i want it to submit and do something else like redirecting to login page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710529/how-to-prevent-user-multiple-click-submit-button-error-for-a-login-form-in-react --> This can provide a solution to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the try block, you can use jQuery's `.submit()` method with the form's ID:

`$("#ID").submit();`

If you're not using jQuery, you can use vanilla JS:

`document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`